# Python script with PyGame mixer running with systemd - ALSA underrun occurred

Tags: python-3.x, systemd, alsa

I have a python script containing some method to play sound with PyGame Mixer on Ubuntu22 with graphical(Desktop) support and I am having trouble running automatically this script with systemd. When I run it manually like python3 /home/user/audio/soundServer.py everything works fine, but when I run systemd service I have this error 'ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred'. I tried many things found on internet but nothing worked. The PC is an I3 10th generation with 8Gb mem and M.2 SSD.

My systemd service look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Audio Server
After=network.target alsa.target pulseaudio.service

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/audio
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/user/audio/soundServer.py
User=user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service starts and is still Active but with this ALSA error, and sound are not playing.

I tried runing the script with python3 /home/user/audio/soundServer.py and it's working fine.
I changed values in /etc/pulse/daeomn.conf:

```
default-fragments = 5
default-fragment-size-msec = 2
```

I tried running the script with CRON and I have the same error.

Is it possible this happen because the desktop is started and maybe it is using the soundcard?

Comment: I've resolved it with adding: Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000